# How to use xml/html tree view for html documents from read_html?

Tags: r, xml, treeview

I want to plot the treeview, of lets say, r-bloggers.com.
I found the awesome XML_tree_view function and the example works fine:

```
library(xml2)
library(htmltidy)
library(magrittr)

txt <- paste0("<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading>",
                             "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>")
xml_tree_view(txt)
```

[image]

Now, i want to load the XML tree from my target site:

```
doc <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com" %>% read_html %>% html_tree_view
```

but nothing appears.

**What i tried:**

```
xml_tree_view(doc)
html_tree_view(doc)
xml_tree_view(doc %>% toString)
html_tree_view(doc %>% toString)
```

Note, i am also perfectly open for `read_hmtl` alternatives like `GET %>% Content`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works as-is. The problem is that you are storing the *view* as `doc`. Remember if you store an object R doesn't automatically call its default print method.

So all you need to do is

```r
"https://www.r-bloggers.com" %>% read_html %>% html_tree_view
```

and you should see the tree view.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
doc <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com" %>% read_html %>% html_tree_view
doc
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer! Thats weird, i still see a blank page on two different Laptops. I try to get other PCs, that i can test further. Sry, if its out of scope, but is it also possible to run it on a stored document? With stored i mean saved to file or variable.